# jQuery backward selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a form and i'm using this to select it's radio buttons:

```
$('form[id^="form-"]').find("input:radio");
```

But when I use a function on it I have to use `this` (so that i'll know from which form the function is fired) and `this` gives me `form > radio-button`. How can I use `this` to get the ID of the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient way is to access the `form` property of the element in question:

```
alert(this.form.id);
```

Comment: @lonesomeday: IE has supported it since at least 5.5, and it's defined in the DOM level 1 spec.

Comment: @lonesomeday: found a link to where it's defined in the spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-6043025

Answer (score 2):

To traverse from the input to its containing form and get the id, you would use:

```
$(this).closest('form[id^="form-"]').attr("id");
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0):

If `this` is a child element just do:

```
var form_id = $(this).parent().get(0).id;
//or
var form_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().attr('id');`

<s>`parents()` is because I don't know if the inputs are direct descendants of form.</s>

Comment: ahhhh dont use `parents` if it is a direct child!

Comment: `form > radio-button` === direct child